# Recommended Minimum SDK for this 2021

Tags: android-studio, android-min-sdk

I want to ask about Android Studio. What is the recommended Minimum SDK for this 2021, I'm currently using api target SDK 31? And how to determine the best Minimum SDK for current latest api? whether browsing on the internet or asking in forums?

Comment: [https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards) says: _"Platform versions: You can find platform version information in Android Studio's Create New Project wizard."_ There are some useful statistics if you click on "Help me choose".

Answer (score 3):

The minimum SDK is the minimum version of Android your app will support. If you would like to support older phones, you should set your minimum SDK level lower, and if you want to reduce code complexity and only support newer phones, you can go with a higher SDK level.

[The numbers correspond with android versions](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platforms).

I would personally recommend supporting Android 5.1+ (minimum SDK of 22) if you do not know where to start, as compatibility with android 4 gets tricky.

Answer (score 0):

I advice to decide what SDK to use in your project based on not only how old device you want to support but also take into consideration how many devices will your app run on. (Unless it's specific none market app.)

Everything you need is in Android studio, right at the page where you create new project and choose Minimum SDK.

#### Here's quick how to:

1. Pick desired SDK
2. Bellow you can see what percentage of devices your app can run on
3. You can click `Help me choose`

[image: Android studio - new project]

3. `Help me choose` will open this graphical representation of all API Distribution and percentage of device your app will run on.

[image: Android platform/ API Version Distribution]

IMHO reasonable solution is choose newest possible SDK that allows your app to run on 80+% of devices

*edit: it was also mentioned in comment by Markus Kauppinen.*